# If there's other data type in the program how can I make it to return error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def calGPAbyLetter(letters):
    ''' (str) -> float OR str
    Take all the grade letters, limited to 10 subjects, and 
    calculate GPA. Grade letters must be A, B, C, D or F.

    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A A A B")
    3.75
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A B B B")
    3.25
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A B B B A C F A D ")
    2.67
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A A A A B B B A C F A D F")
    'Error'
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A A A A B C F A D F")
    2.6
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("S A B C F A D F")
    'Error'

    '''
    tGP = 0.0
    letter = map(str, letters.split())
    if len (letter) > 10:
        return "Error"
    for i in letter:
        gp = checkGP(i)
        if gp is str:
            return gp
        tGP = tGP + gp
    return round(tGP / len(letter), 2)
def checkGP(letter):
    ''' (str) -> int OR str
    Assign grade point from grade letter.
    Grade letters must be A, B, C, D or F.

    >>> checkGP('A')
    4
    >>> checkGP('B')
    3
    >>> checkGP('S')
    'Error'
    '''
    if letter < 0:
        return "Error"
    elif letter == "F":
        return 0.0
    elif letter == "D":
        return 1.0
    elif letter == "C":
        return 2.0
    elif letter == "B":
        return 3.0
    elif letter == "A":
        return 4.0
    else:
        return "Error"
```

Now when I input

```
calGPAbyLetter("A A A S")
```

it returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    calGPAbyLetter("A A A B A A A A S")
  File "/Users/Sahiphopz/Documents/Programming and Algorithm/a05.py", line 30, in calGPAbyLetter
    tGP = tGP + gp
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
what to do to fix this please help
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that

```
if gp is str:
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `str` is a class which represents strings.  So your code is saying is `gp` the same as the class `str`, which it isn't. What you need to do is:

```
if type(gp) == str:
```

Take the following example:

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()

print(a is A)
```

This creates a class called `A`, and an instance of this class called `a`. While `a` is of type `A`, it itself is not `A`, and therefore

```
print(a is A)
```

will print `False`.

This is what is causing the error in your code. The if statement is failing to do what you expect, and so your code is trying to add `tGP`, which is a float and `gp` which is set to `"Error"`, which is causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

You can return False instead of a string "ERROR" like so,

```
def calGPAbyLetter(letters):
    ''' (str) -> float OR str
    Take all the grade letters, limited to 10 subjects, and 
    calculate GPA. Grade letters must be A, B, C, D or F.

    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A A A B")
    3.75
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A B B B")
    3.25
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A B B B A C F A D ")
    2.67
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A A A A B B B A C F A D F")
    'Error'
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("A A A A B C F A D F")
    2.6
    >>> calGPAbyLetter("S A B C F A D F")
    'Error'

    '''
    tGP = 0.0
    letter = map(str, letters.split())
    if len (letter) > 10:
        return False
    for i in letter:
        gp = checkGP(i)
        if gp is str:
            return gp
        tGP = tGP + gp
    return round(tGP / len(letter), 2)
def checkGP(letter):
    ''' (str) -> int OR str
    Assign grade point from grade letter.
    Grade letters must be A, B, C, D or F.

    >>> checkGP('A')
    4
    >>> checkGP('B')
    3
    >>> checkGP('S')
    'Error'
    '''
    if letter < 0:
        return False
    elif letter == "F":
        return 0.0
    elif letter == "D":
        return 1.0
    elif letter == "C":
        return 2.0
    elif letter == "B":
        return 3.0
    elif letter == "A":
        return 4.0
    else:
        return False

print calGPAbyLetter("A A A S")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as it says in the error, is that you are trying to add a `str` to a `float`. You account for this by checking  if `gp` is a `str`, but your method doesn't work. `gp` is of type `str`, while `str` is a type itself, so checking

`if gp is str`

will not work, because they are not comparable. Instead, replace that line with this:

`if type(gp) == str`

or

`if gp == "Error"`

Either of these should work instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a clearer way of structuring your logic.

```
def calGPAbyLetter(letters):

    letter = list(map(str, letters.split()))

    if len(letter) > 10:
        raise Exception('Maximum of 10 grades permitted')

    grades = list(map(checkGP, letter))

    return round(sum(grades) / len(grades), 2)

def checkGP(letter):
    d = {'F': 0, 'D': 1, 'C': 2, 'B': 3, 'A': 4}
    try:
        return d[letter]
    except KeyError:
        print('Unmapped grade supplied')
```

**Explanation**

- Don't return ambiguous "Error" strings. Raise specific errors or exceptions and give some meaning to the result.
- Use a dictionary within `checkGP` instead of an `if` / `else` construct.
- There is no need to use an explicit loop to aggregate grade values. You can use `map(checkGP, letter)` to run the function on each value of the `letter` list.